# Encrypt all characters of the first parameter by shifting each character by the second parameter

Tags: javascript, encryption

**Input string will always be in uppercase. No need to shift any non-alpha characters.**

*Example :
Encrypt(‘ABC’, 4) should return "EFG"*

- The return type should be a string.
- encrypt("ABC", 4) Should equal to “EFG”
- encrypt("AB C", 2) Should equal to “CD E”
- encrypt("ABC DEF", 2) Should equal to “CDE FGH”
- The answer should be valid for any given input.

> function encrypt(str, index) {
>         var encryptedstr = '';
>         return encryptedstr;
>       }
>
> ```
> encrypt('ABC', 4);
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What don't you know how to do? Do you know how to read the `n`th character of a string? Do you know how to determine if a character is in the range of `A` to `Z`? Do you know how find a letter that is `x` letters down the alphabet from another? Do you know how to concatenate the result? Every one of these questions is suitably scopes for a Stack Overflow question (but before you ask them, make sure you can't solve them yourself with a quick search), which this question is way too broad, because it encompasses all of these sub-questions, and it's not clear what you know and what you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> function findWordsWithLengthRange(str, min, max) {   var words =
>   str.split(" ");   var wordCount = 0;   for (i = 0; i < words.length;
>   i++)   {
>       if(words[i].length >= min && words[i].length <= max)
>       {
>         wordCount++;
>       }   }   return wordCount; }
>
> findWordsWithLengthRange("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
>   dog", 2, 3);